# Android to enable the button upon onAnimationEnded

Tags: android, animation

I have implemented an animation to the ButtonNext button such  that when the user answers the questions correctly, the buttonNext will animate by like flipping a card, from the original faceup to the bottom green facedown.

### The coding is as follows:

```
isBlackShowing = false;
if (temp.equals(correct_answer))
{           
    buttonNext.clearAnimation();
    buttonNext.setAnimation(to_middle);
    buttonNext.startAnimation(to_middle);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
{
    if (isBlackShowing == false)
    {       
        buttonNext.setText("Next!");

        buttonNext.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_btn);                 
        buttonNext.clearAnimation();
        buttonNext.setAnimation(from_middle);           
        buttonNext.startAnimation(from_middle);     
    }           
        isBlackShowing = true;
        buttonNext.setEnabled(true);            
}
```

### Questions:

I would like the ButtonNext be enabled only when all the animation is finished, i.e. showing properly the green faceDown.

Yet with the above codes, I discover that the button will be already enabled and users are free to jump to next, next and next questions if keep pressing the button during the animation.

How could the above malfunction be fixed??

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why don't you disable it after animation started. If it blocks animation also, you could write 2 onClickListener and making one of them null (no code in it) then swap the listener of button by setOnClickListener. Didn't test şt though, just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the listener of button as I suggested like;

```
final View.OnClickListener first= new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText("first");

        }
    };
    final View.OnClickListener second= new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText("second");

        }
    };
    Button swap= (Button) findViewById(R.id.swap);
    final Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    swap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(a==1)
            {
                btn.setOnClickListener(first);
                a=2;
            }
            else{
                btn.setOnClickListener(second);
                a=1;
            }

        }
    });
```

I'm using a button called swap to do that to test it quickly and it worked. It's seems like that is what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks a lot for your advice! i am trying to implement your suggestion but then thinking then in the same layout at the same place the 2 buttons are overlapping to each other such that one and the other is set to be visible and invisible from time to time?

Comment: It's not two buttons, you will set your but clicklistener. I just used second button to test swap, you will do it by calling setOnClickListener() by your animate function.